# $G_\delta$ set of nowhere differentiable functions?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

I'm trying to show that in $C([0,1])$ with the supremum metric, there exists a dense $G_\delta$ set of nowhere differentiable functions. Honestly, I don't know how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I recommend reading: https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/almost-all-continuous-functions-are-nowhere-differentiable/

Answer (score 0):

The density of nowhere-differentiable functions is a rather deep result, and a classical application of the Baire category theorem. [Here](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_09/papers/Dylan.pdf) is a nice treatment (see proposition 3). To express the nowhere-differentiable functions as a $G_\delta$ set should require only a slight modification of the linked proof.